# Javascript change input value

Tags: javascript, html

In my website I have a box that is not displayed. When the user types his username and password, if they are correct, the box must be displayed. Here you see the HTML code:

```
<div id="mainbox" style="display: none;">
    <p class="classm">Test.</p>
</div>    
<input type="text" id="user"/>
<br />
<input type="text" id="password" value="a"/>
<br />
<input type="button" value="Log in" onclick="login();">
```

And here the javascript function:

```
function login() {
    var a = document.getElementById('password').value;
    var b = document.getElementById('user').value;
    if ((a == 'qwe') && (b == 'rty')) { //the problem is not here
     document.getElementById('password').style.display="none";
    }
    else
    {
     alert('You are not logged in.');  
    }
}
```

When I click the button `Log in` looks like the function `login();` is not called because anything happen. Do you know why?

Comment: Are you sure you are typing the right letters in the right box? The first box needs to be 'rty' and the second 'qwe'.

Comment: working fine: http://jsfiddle.net/5dgtz/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (a == 'qwe') && (b == 'rty') //Wrong
```

Enclose the condition like **`if( condition )`**

```
 if ((a == 'qwe') && (b == 'rty') ) //Corect
```

As @Frédéric Hamidi suggested, there is **no need of inner parentheses**.

Simple like this

```
if (a == 'qwe' && b == 'rty' )
```

Demo **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/fT9uK/)**

Comment: Nitpicking: `==` has more precedence than `&&`, so the inner parentheses are not required.

Comment: @AlbertoRossi, I think you have a & b mixed, `a` should be user, and `b` pass, or? I added a demo to this answer. Check it out.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi You're right, I have included in it in my answer.  Thanks for the pointers.

Answer (score 2):

use proper if

```
if (a == 'qwe' && b == 'rty' )
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/EYSg8/)